# Openweather.com API 5 next days forecast issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is my first time using openweather.com API for weather forecasts, I just want to show the following information for the next 5 days:

Min and Max temperature of each day
Weather icon
Current weather description (Drizzle, Sunny...)

Plain simple, for some reason I'm getting pretty weird results, take a look at the image bellow so you can understand (I THINK that this five results are actually of the same day, different timestamps, look at min/max temp, maybe? instead of the next 5 days...

[image]

This is my code:

```
async getForecast()
    {
        let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";
        let payload = 
        {
            lat: this.$app.globals.origin.lat,
            lon: this.$app.globals.origin.lng,
            units: 'metric',
            APPID: '0feb06072d87320932559f321ca221fb',
            lang:'es',
            cnt:5
        };

        let response = await axios.get(url, { params: payload });
        this.data = response.data.list;
    }
```

In my view (Vue.js):

```
<div style="width:auto; height:100%; display:flex; align-items:center;">
                <a  style="width:auto; padding:10; height:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; justify-content:space-around;" v-for="(item,index) in data" :key="index">
                    <span class="fs_smaller c_normal">{{ item.main.temp_min }} / {{ item.main.temp_max }}</span>
                    <span class="fs_smaller c_normal">{{ item.weather[0].description }}</span>
                    <img style="width:50px; height:auto;" :src="'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/'+item.weather[0].icon+'.png'">
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API endpoint you're hitting is the 3-hour-forecast for the next 5 days:
https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

If you inspect the response, you'll see a `dt_txt` property in the `list` items. There you can see that the items are 3 hours apart.

You could use the daily forecast, which has the same API schema, it just adds a `/daily` to the URL:
https://openweathermap.org/forecast16

You could extract the values like this:

```js
import _ from "lodash"
const itemsByDay = _.groupBy(response.list, item => item.dt_txt.slice(0, 10))
const extrema = _.mapValues(itemsByDay, items => ({
    min: _.min(_.map(items, 'main.temp_min')),
    max: _.max(_.map(items, 'main.temp_max')),
}))
```

Comment: It seems that endpoint is part of the paid plans, is there really no way to get the forecast for next 5 days without paying?

Comment: You could just group them by days (I would use lodash's `groupBy`) and for each day compute the min and max. If you need help doing this, I'll guide you.

Comment: Well I'm pretty lost right now, I have used lodash before but I'm not very familiar with openweather api responses, if you want to post a piece of code I'd really appreciate it, I just want to have icon + min/max average for next 5 days ...

Comment: Added a script in the answer. Hope it helps you.